# Call Javascript function from Windows Phone 7/Silverlight

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I want to authenticate to a an external web page from my windows phone application.  I will then want to do further scraping of pages on the site but need to get past the authentication issue.

The page on the external website has a function call validateLogin which takes login name and password.

I want to call this function from my Windows Phone code passing in the required arguments.  This would facilitate logging into the site and hopefully I can continue to scrape the pages.

Comment: Check this posts:
[Calling JavaScript Functions in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/26/calling-javascript-functions-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WebBrowser` control and call the `InvokeScript` method. Ensure that you set `IsScriptEnabled` on the `WebBrowser` control and that you specify the ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT capability in WMAppManifest.xml.

As a side note: Scraping web pages is rarely a robust and reliable approach of creating an application that uses a website :)

Comment: Yeah I know scraping is fragile - but no option - it doesn't change much so hopefully its manageable.

Comment: There is no api, web service or rss type interface.  Can you suggest any other alternatives?